# Image gets bigger when forwarding email template

Tags: html, css, image, email

So I designed an email template from Marketo. When I send the email to myself it views perfectly fine:
[image]
as you can see the image size here looks completely fine, but the problem is when I try and forward the email the image size becomes very huge I have no idea why. It looks like this when I forward:
[image]

my code to view the image is:

```
<div id="cover" class="mktEditable" style="" mktoname="cover">
                          <p class="no-spacing" style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Thumbnail_Demystifying-AutoFinance.png" style="max-width: 100%; width: 180px; height: auto" /></p>
                        </div>
```

How can I make it a fixed size?

Comment: if need entire code, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

> It’s common knowledge that email clients all render email differently. When a subscriber forwards an email, some email clients make changes to the code of the forwarded message. This can include stripping out certain HTML elements, wrapping your email in a blockquote, or inserting additional classes to your code—all of which can break your design and make the email less functional for the recipient of the forwarded email.

Here’s an example of a button that breaks when the email is forwarded:
[image]
[image]

Source: https://litmus.com/blog/when-forwarded-emails-break

Answer (score 0):

Try to add width="180" in < img > tag.

`<div id="cover" class="mktEditable" style="" mktoname="cover"><p class="no-spacing" style="text-align: center;"><img width="180" src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Thumbnail_Demystifying-AutoFinance.png" style="height: auto" /></p></div>`